# C# colocar uma condição para um valor duma coluna num DataGridView com DataSource

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

Estou utilizando VS2013 Entity 5.
A situação é a seguinte:

Numa tabela de Filhos, há um atributo sexoFilho que recebe o valor 0, 1.
0 para masculino e 1 para feminino.  (poderia usar "m" ou "f", mas é uma situação de aprendizagem)

Em meu DataGridView, na coluna Sexo aparecem, então, os valores 0 e 1. 
Como eu poderia colocar uma condição para que ao invés desses valores, apareçam "M" ou "F"?

```
dsFilhos.Tables("filhos").Columns("sexoFilho").Expression ="IIF(sexoFilho='0', 'M', 'F')";
```

Pesquisei sobre calc fields mas não fui bem sucedido. Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Pode colocar na sua pergunta como está o código até agora?

Comment: Código editado. Estou utilizando aquele código, mas ele diz ser uma "referência circular"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você falou sobre `CalcFields`, aparentemente você veio do Delphi. No Webforms, as coisas não são tão diferentes. O que muda é o evento que você vai usar para exibir os valores.

No caso, o evento correto é o [`dataGridView.CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx), que aceita um *delegate* do tipo [`DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellformattingeventhandler(v=vs.118).aspx). Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

## `Page_Load`

```
dsFilhos.CellFormatting += new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellFormatting);
```

## No mesmo fonte

```
void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dsFilhos.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "sexoFilho")
    {
        if (e.Value == null)
            return;

        string stringValue = (string)e.Value;
        stringValue = stringValue.ToLower();

        switch (stringValue) {
            case "m":
                e.Value = "Masculino";
            case "f":
                e.Value = "Feminino";
            default:
                e.Value = "Indefinido";
        }

        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!